# How to change the default return amount - MailChimp API Json

Tags: arrays, json, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am having trouble. Trouble which i am sure is but a moments thought to resolve for our resident experts but, i must learn...

I am returning lists and as I understand it the default return is 25. I have a total of 93.

Below is what i am using (minus our API Key)

http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=lists&apikey=

I believe that i need a piece of code [limit]=100 as MailChimp suggests but there are numerous pieces of advice on the website and after trying all i am still without my desired output.

If you could advise the way to do this I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Will. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit should work:

```
http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=lists&apikey=YOUR_KEY&limit=100
```

It was working perfectly fine for me. Check if you are in the right region (in my case I was in us13).